# Xcode can't launch application in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

when I start my app, this error appear
[image]

Xcode 9, Swift 4, MacOS HighSierra

after starting the app, Xcode stock for attaching app to simulator

[image]

Comment: quite the simulator and run again

Comment: sometime its happened on initial launch.

Comment: reopen the simulator couldn't help. not sometimes, always

Comment: If reopen simulator couldn't help, try to restart mac. I have this Error more then 3-5 times on a day and rebuild project usually helps.

Comment: Try cleaning the product via Product > Clean and then re-building the project.

Comment: yes I did it before, but it's not the solution

Answer (score 0):

try to delete derived data or complete indexing then bulid

Comment: how can I complete the indexing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you are working on Xcode 9 and its simulator then some other Xcode's simulator should not remain open. Close it and run. Or sometimes this may happen on the first launch of our app

Comment: U are getting this error always? Did u open any other XCode or simulator other than Xcode 9 and its simulator?

Comment: yes always, no I open Xcode and run the application, Xcode opens the simulator itself automatically

Comment: Did u try quitting xcode, simulator and restarting them?